# How to set two column having two different selection criteria in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to set two column having two different selection criteria in crystal report?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about different Record Selection criteria for each column... in the truest sense, it's not possible.

A possible workaround is using formula fields for your two columns and adding data logic within those formulas.

For example, say you want Column 1 to show values where a field is equal to 'A' and Column 2 to show values where a field is equal to 'B':

{@Column1Field}:
if {table.column1field} = "A" then
   {table.column1field}
else
   ""

{@Column2Field}:
if {table.column2field} = "B" then
   {table.column2field}
else
   ""